# Writing to file in Android and viewing it

Tags: android, file, io, sd-card

I am creating an application which needs to fetch data from the net and re-organize the same. For testing, i just want to write the contents of the HTML response to a file within the project workspace so as to view it and come up with a reorganizing logic.

Is it possible to write and view the file from my system? If we write it to SD card, where will be the file stored in the project workspace during the development?

Answer (score 1):

You can pull files from the emulator/device using `adb pull <path>`.

If you're having trouble finding your file you can use `adb shell ls <path>` to poke around the device filesystem. Usually the mount point for the SD card is `/mnt/sdcard`.

The files you download while your program is running never make it back to the development workspace.